# CONCAT with IF condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have a table with four columns presenting {YES, NO, N/A} values. What I'd like to obtain is a column with concatenated names of those columns which present a 'YES' value separate by a double underscore.

```
\, A, B, C, D
1, YES, NO, YES, N/A
2, NO, YES, N/A, N/A
3, YES, NO, NO, YES
```

Expected result:

```
A__C
B
A__D
```

Something like:

```
select CONCAT(
IF(A = 'YES', 'A'),
IF(B = 'YES', 'B'),
IF(C = 'YES', 'C'),
IF(D = 'YES', 'D'))
from my_table
```

Comment: Use [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope I understand you right, that you want a double underscore separator. 
This solution works without any subquery or cte processing.

```
select substring(
           iif(a='YES','__A','') + iif(b='YES','__B','') + 
           iif(c='YES','__C','') + iif(d='YES','__D','')
       ,3,100) 
from table1
```

One should know that this: `substring('', 3, 100)` will work using SqlServer.

Comment: This worked just fine and seems to be the more compact solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `T1` is your table:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(X)>0 THEN LEFT(X, LEN(X)-2) ELSE '' END AS Y
 FROM (
     SELECT 
     CASE WHEN A='YES' THEN 'A__' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN B='YES' THEN 'B__' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN C='YES' THEN 'C__' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN D='YES' THEN 'D__' ELSE '' END AS X
     FROM T1
     ) A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH ABC 
as 
( 
Select 
    (
    CASE WHEN A = 'YES' THEN 'A_' ELSE '' END as A +
    CASE WHEN B = 'YES' THEN 'B_' ELSE '' END as B +
    CASE WHEN C = 'YES' THEN 'C_' ELSE '' END as C +
    CASE WHEN D = 'YES' THEN 'D_' ELSE '' END as D 
    ) as output
)
Select case when len(output) = 2 then left (output,1)
       else output
       end as output
From ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select case A then 'YES' then 'A' else '_'end + case B then 'YES' then 'B' else '_'end +case C then 'YES' then 'C' else '_'end +case D then 'YES' then 'D' else '_'end as result from my_table
```